# Seed Torrent with Folders from Zip or other archive file

Tags: bittorrent, archiving

Wanting to provide a seed for a folder of data that people request infrequently, do I have a way to seed this torrent from a Zip or other archive file? I would accept willingly the additional overhead that extraction would incur with the conservation of disk space from the archival. I know I could create a new torrent with just the archive file; let's imagine that I don't have an account to register torrents with a particular tracker.

I would want to know an answer, even if the archive file did no compression, though I would prefer a file with compression, of course. I know some filesystems offer compression natively, but I am looking for a solution above the filesystem level.

I imagine this would involve a particular Torrent client, and maybe even a proprietary archive format. In my case, I am using **transmission** on Debian. I would accept answers regarding clients on other operating systems as well, though I may not use the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Windows file and folder compression would handle this transparently. No special features or automated decompression features required.

Seriously, I don't think you even need to enable general file/folder compression on the drive.

Just right-click on the file or folder, select Properties, click Advanced, and then select "Compress contents to save space".

Comment: This helped me in an unrelated application; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`archivemount` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivemount) mounts an archive file with FUSE. From this directory, you can seed your torrent.

```
archivemount -o readonly /path/to/archive.zip /path/to/dir
```

Many distributions contain this package in their main (OSS) repository.